# apache 2.4, Windows Server 2012 unable to access new files in htdocs

Tags: apache, windows-server-2012-r2, php-7.1

I have Apache 2.4, MySql 4.1 and PHP 7.1 installed on a windows server2012 r2.

I can test that Apache is installed by browsing http://localhost/ so that the website shows the content of the index.html file already present in htdocs, but I cannot access the file test.php in the htdocs folder by http://localhost/test.php/ I get the error content not found the row in the Apache error report is 
                        [Wed Apr 26 12:54:22.400615 2017] [:error] [pid 1068:tid 1020] [client ::1:61536] script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/index.php' not found or unable to stat

I have done a number of tests and what seems weird to me it that if i copy the content of test.php in index.html, it works and I get the right page with information about php installation.
So I thought it was a matter of security settings but I am the owner of the folder and I did the installion.

Does anyone have any idea about that?

Thanks

Comment: Try to check the test.php file permission and set it as index.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. I got the problem file's name was test.php but its extension is php so i had a sort of test.php.php .